# ffmpeg converted mp4 video format is not playing on html5 video player

Tags: php, wordpress, html, video, ffmpeg

i have converted a video via ffmpeg to mp4 but its playing on desktop pc player like Vlc but not on html5 player or wordpress player.

Iam using this command while conversion:

```
ffmpeg." -i ".$video_to_convert." -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -preset slow -c:a libfaac -b:a 192k -ac 2 -b:a ".$quality." -acodec libmp3lame -ab 126000 -ar ".$audio." -ac 2 -s ".$size." ".$converted_vids.$name.".".$new_format."
```

where:

.$video_to_convert. = input.mp4

.$converted_vids.$name. = output.mp4

is there any syntax problem??????????????????

Comment: Remove `-acodec libmp3lame -ab 126000`. You may want to add `-movflags +faststart`, and depending on browser, `-profile:v main`

Comment: i changed but yet getting same error

Comment: @alina 1) Try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. 2) You must be using a really old version since you're using libfaac (support for that mediocre encoder was removed from FFmpeg): see the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to recent versions for Linux, macOS, and Windows. 3) Show the actual, unscripted command being used and show the complete console output/log from your command.

Comment: after adding that, videos are giving prompt command to download instead of playing

Comment: in wordpress player